# for making html form attach with mysql database i get error̥ which says:Exception Type: ValueError Exception Value

Tags: python, mysql, django, web

I am binding my html form to mysql database table in django after running the server the form is visible in the browser but after clicking on submit this error occurs which says
after filling the form and clicking on submit button I get following error

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view Insertemp.views.Insertrecord didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from Insertemp.models import EmpInsert

from django.contrib import messages

#from django.http import HttpResponse


def Insertrecord(request):
   

    if request.method=='POST':
        
        
        if request.POST.get('pname')and request.POST.get('pcategory')and request.POST.get('pdetails')and request.POST.get('foundedin')and request.POST.get('orderoftest')and request.POST.get('t1')and request.POST.get('t2')and request.POST.get('t3')and request.POST.get('f1')and request.POST.get('f2')and request.POST.get('f3')and request.POST.get('f4')and request.POST.get('f5'):    

            saverecord=EmpInsert()

            saverecord.pname=request.POST.get('pname')

            saverecord.pcategory=request.POST.get('pcategory')

            saverecord.pdetails=request.POST.get('pdetails')

            saverecord.foundedin=request.POST.get('foundedin')

            saverecord.foundedin=request.POST.get('orderoftestimonial')

            saverecord.t1=request.POST.get('t1')

            saverecord.t2=request.POST.get('t2')

            saverecord.t3=request.POST.get('t3')

            saverecord.f1=request.POST.get('f1')

            saverecord.f2=request.POST.get('f2')

            saverecord.f3=request.POST.get('f3')

            saverecord.f4=request.POST.get('f4')

            saverecord.f5=request.POST.get('f5')
            saverecord.save()

            messages.success(request,'Record Saved Successfully...!')
            
            
            
            

            return render(request,'Index.html')
        

    else:        
    

         return render(request,'Index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap in your checks so it's returning none, because it's a post request but doesn't pass your `if` data check;

```
def Insertrecord(request):
   

    if request.method=='POST':
        
        
        if request.POST.get('pname')and request.POST.get('pcategory')and request.POST.get('pdetails')and request.POST.get('foundedin')and request.POST.get('orderoftest')and request.POST.get('t1')and request.POST.get('t2')and request.POST.get('t3')and request.POST.get('f1')and request.POST.get('f2')and request.POST.get('f3')and request.POST.get('f4')and request.POST.get('f5'):    

            ...

            messages.success(request,'Record Saved Successfully...!')
            
            return render(request,'Index.html')

        # Here it returns None because it's a POST request 
        # but not into the above block
        # return something at this point to avoid the black hole
        return render(request, 'Index.html')
    else:        
        return render(request,'Index.html')
```

You should also probably pass some context back with the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) so that you can identify what happened in the view once you're rendering the template.

Comment: sir exatly what i must add can u please explain in detail

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM add the section before the `else`, I've explained in the comment there.

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM I would also recommend you research django forms. Once you understand how they can work for you, they would simplify your templates and views massively. They'll also take care of validation of data for you.

Comment: sir actually i had made django html forms earlier also but i dont konw why this time it giving me problem